# Duplicate word in hangman game Python

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have a problem, when in Hangman game there is a word like happy, it only append 1 'p' in the list...run my code and please tell me what to do? 
check my loops.

```
import random
import time
File=open("Dict.txt",'r')
Data = File.read()
Word = Data.split("\n")

A = random.randint(0,len(Word)-1)

Dict = Word[A]

print(Dict)
Dash = []
print("\n\n\t\t\t","_ "*len(Dict),"\n\n")
i = 0
while i < len(Dict):

    letter = str(input("\n\nEnter an alphabet: "))
    if letter == "" or letter not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' or len(letter) != 1:
        print("\n\n\t\tPlease Enter Some valid thing\n\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        i = i - 1

    if letter in Dict:
        Dash.append(letter)
    else:
        print("This is not in the word")
        i = i - 1


    for item in Dict:
        if item in Dash:
            print(item, end = " ")
        else:
            print("_", end = " ")

    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with the "break" on Line 25: once you have filled in one space with the letter "p", the loop breaks and will not fill in the second space with "p".

You need to have a flag variable to remember whether any space has been successfully filled in, like this:

```
success = False
for c in range(len(Dict)):
  if x == Dict[c]:
    Dash[c] = x
    success = True
if not success:
  Lives -= 1
```

P.S. There's something wrong with the indentation of the code you have posted.